# Criar elementos com informações Json

Tags: javascript, json

Estou a criar um programa onde eu tenho um objeto json e eu quero exibir ele em um  que estou criando via script mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo criar esses elementos, quando chega na função view ela não cia os elementos solicitados.. Por favor se puderem me deem uma luz. 
segue o code:

HTML:

```
<form>
        <div id="decoding" class="aling"></div>
      </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function view(objJson){
  var box = document.querySelector('div#decoding')
  box.setAttribute('class', 'shadow')

  var challenge = document.createElement('fieldset')
  challenge.setAttribute('class', 'painting')
  var legendChallenge = document.createElement('legend')
  legendChallenge.innerHTML('Challenge')
  challenge.innerHTML(`Número de casas: ${objJson["numero_casas"]}<br>
  Token: ${objJson["token"]}<br>
  Cifrado: ${objJson["cifrado"]}<br>
  Decifrado: ${objJson["decifrado"]}<br>
  Resumo Criptografico: ${objJson["resumo_criptografico"]}`)

  var answer = document.createElement('fieldset')
  answer.setAttribute('class', 'painting')
  var legendAnswer  = document.createElement('legend')
  legendAnswer.innerHTML('Answer')
  answer.innerHTML(`Número de casas: ${objJson["numero_casas"]}<br>
  Token: ${objJson["token"]}<br>
  Cifrado: ${objJson["cifrado"]}<br>
  Decifrado: ${objJson["decifrado"]}<br>
  Resumo Criptografico: ${objJson["resumo_criptografico"]}`)

  box.appendChild(challenge)
  box.appendChild(answer)
  challenge.appendChild(legendChallenge)
  answer.appendChild(legendAnswer)
}
```

A variável objJson guarda esse valor: `{"numero_casas":9,"token":"68c56aa784fe216ae92720b76386ea0995055074","cifrado":"fqnw rw mxdkc, unjen rc xdc. sxbqdj kuxlq","decifrado":"","resumo_criptografico":""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tadeu, o erro está apenas no innerHTML, pois trata-se de uma propriedade, e não uma função:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

---

Corrigindo essa parte, seu código funcionou:

```js
function view(objJson){

  var box = document.querySelector('div#decoding');
  box.setAttribute('class', 'shadow');

  var challenge = document.createElement('fieldset');
  challenge.setAttribute('class', 'painting');

  var legendChallenge = document.createElement('legend');
  legendChallenge.innerHTML = 'Challenge';
  challenge.innerHTML = `Número de casas: ${objJson["numero_casas"]}<br>
  Token: ${objJson["token"]}<br>
  Cifrado: ${objJson["cifrado"]}<br>
  Decifrado: ${objJson["decifrado"]}<br>
  Resumo Criptografico: ${objJson["resumo_criptografico"]}`;

  var answer = document.createElement('fieldset');
  answer.setAttribute('class', 'painting');

  var legendAnswer  = document.createElement('legend');
  legendAnswer.innerHTML = 'Answer';

  answer.innerHTML = `Número de casas: ${objJson["numero_casas"]}<br>
  Token: ${objJson["token"]}<br>
  Cifrado: ${objJson["cifrado"]}<br>
  Decifrado: ${objJson["decifrado"]}<br>
  Resumo Criptografico: ${objJson["resumo_criptografico"]}`;

  box.appendChild(challenge);
  box.appendChild(answer);
  challenge.appendChild(legendChallenge);
  answer.appendChild(legendAnswer);
}

view({"numero_casas":9,"token":"68c56aa784fe216ae92720b76386ea0995055074","cifrado":"fqnw rw mxdkc, unjen rc xdc. sxbqdj kuxlq","decifrado":"","resumo_criptografico":""});
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="decoding" class="aling"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: PUTS, que erro tolo que cometi! E estava sego para isso, valeu Daniel. gratidão.